# Event after double animation whilst keeping context

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create an animation but am having problems executing some code after the animation has occured. The animation code is as follows...

```
public static void Friend(Canvas canvas)
{
    foreach (var element in canvas.Children.OfType<Image>())
    {
        var elementName = Regex.Split(element.Name, "_");
        if (elementName[0] == "friend")
        {
            var slideDown = new DoubleAnimation
                {
                    From = Canvas.GetBottom(element),
                    To = Canvas.GetBottom(element) - element.Height,
                    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
                    AutoReverse = true
                };
            element.BeginAnimation(Canvas.BottomProperty, slideDown);
            slideDown.Completed += (sender, e) => Test(sender, e, element, canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

The event to happen afterwards is...

```
var random = new Random();
element.Source = Core.StreamImage(Wardrobe.Friends[Wardrobe.RandomFriend()]);
Canvas.SetLeft(element, random.Next(0, (int)(canvas.ActualWidth - element.Width)));
// then reverse the previous animation.
```

As you can see, the event needs to keep the context of the animation in order for it to work but event handlers don't allow this. I have tried adding this code directly underneath the `element.BeginAnimation` but it is executed prematurely.

I have also tried splitting the parts of the animation up into seperate functions but of course you can't have multiple animations on one object as the functions don't get executed in order resulting in only the last section being played.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the event above the execution

```
public static void Friend(Canvas canvas)
{
    foreach (var element in canvas.Children.OfType<Image>())
    {
        var elementName = Regex.Split(element.Name, "_");
        if (elementName[0] == "friend")
        {
            var slideDown = new DoubleAnimation
                {
                    From = Canvas.GetBottom(element),
                    To = Canvas.GetBottom(element) - element.Height,
                    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
                    AutoReverse = true
                };
            slideDown.Completed += (sender, e) => Test(sender, e, element, canvas);
            element.BeginAnimation(Canvas.BottomProperty, slideDown);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% but I think the Animation becomes Freezable after it executes, so we cant modify after

BTW, you can have multiple animations on a object but you need to use "StoryBoard".

Storyboard example:

```
 var slideDown = new DoubleAnimation { From = 100, To = 200, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)), AutoReverse = true };
 var slideLeft = new DoubleAnimation { From = 100, To = 200, BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)), AutoReverse = true };

 Storyboard storyBoard = new Storyboard();
 storyBoard.Children.Add(slideDown);
 storyBoard.Children.Add(slideLeft);
 Storyboard.SetTargetName(slideDown, myCanvas.Name);
 Storyboard.SetTargetName(slideLeft, myCanvas.Name);
 Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slideLeft, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
 Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slideDown, new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty));

 myCanvas.BeginStoryboard(storyBoard);
```

Comment: Thanks, i actually managed to figure it out just before i got your reply. It was partly because of not placing the ``Completed`` event before starting the animation but i also managed to add inline code as a event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code i used to fix the problem i was having...

```
public static void Friend(Canvas canvas)
{
    var random = new Random();
    foreach (var element in canvas.Children.OfType<Image>())
    {
        var elementName = Regex.Split(element.Name, "_");
        if (elementName[0] == "friend")
        {
            var slideDown = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                From = Canvas.GetBottom(element),
                To = Canvas.GetBottom(element) - element.Height,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            };
            slideDown.Completed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                element.Source = Core.StreamImage(Wardrobe.Friends[Wardrobe.RandomFriend()]);
                Canvas.SetLeft(element, random.Next(0, (int)(canvas.ActualWidth - element.Width)));
                var slideUp = new DoubleAnimation
                {
                    From = Canvas.GetBottom(element),
                    To = Canvas.GetBottom(element) + element.Height,
                    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                };
                element.BeginAnimation(Canvas.BottomProperty, slideUp);
            };
            element.BeginAnimation(Canvas.BottomProperty, slideDown);
        }
    }
}
```